# Getting image URL of uploaded image

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there a way to allow users to upload images from their devices/computer from an HTML upload input that gets the image URL of an uploaded image and puts it into an array. Whatever method works but my end goal is getting an image uploaded to the Mongo database in either image format or by the URL. I am trying to go for the solution that has the smallest amount of code and uses the least amount of frameworks. I know about the Meteor package that allows the users to upload files but I just want to know if there is a simpler solution that requires no frameworks or extremely long pieces of code. Preferably in react as well would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
'click #explorer': function() {
    $("#file-upload").click();
  },
  'change #file-upload': function() {
    var photoid = $('#photoid').val();
    encodeImageFileAsURL(photoid);

    function encodeImageFileAsURL(photoid) {
      var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file-upload").files;
      if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
          var photo = {
            srcData: fileLoadedEvent.target.result,
            userid: Meteor.userId(),
            photo_id: photoid
          }

          Meteor.call('addPhoto', photo)
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
      }
    }
    $('#photoid').val('');
  },
```

html

```
<div class=" row ">
          <div class=" col-xs-12 ">
              <div>
              {{#if photo}}
                <img id="explorer" style="width: 130px;height: 130px;border-radius: 50%;margin: 0 auto;" class="img-responsive" src='{{photo}}' alt=""  />
              {{else}}
                    <img id="explorer" class="img-responsive img-circle" src="/persona2.png"  width="120px" alt="" />
              {{/if}}
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12" id="">
                  <div class="popuptext"  id="myPopup">
                  <img class="img-responsive" id="explorer"  src="/pencil.png" alt="" style="width: 43px;margin-left: 86px;margin-top: -43px;"/>
                  <image id="Browser" src=""/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="photoid"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
            <input id="file-upload" style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
```

Meteor Methods addPhoto

```
    updatePhoto: function( photo)  {

      Meteor.users.update({'_id' : photo.userid},{$set:{'profile.photo_1': photo.srcData}},{"multi" : false, "upsert" : false});

  }
```

Comment: Where is the addPhoto method? Is that a built in method by meteor?

Comment: a collection where you indicate where to save the image with mongo. Add the post method.  {{#if photo}} is the helpers , where you ask the collection if you have the data you load it if you do not have anything saved with that reference then it shows the default image

Comment: The files returned are in an object, is there anyway to get the imageURL out of it, I can't seem to find a way to get it from an html input.